# Google YouTube OAuth API Error 403: org_internal This client is restricted to users within its organization

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to give myself permission to our brand channel so I can upload videos using the YouTube Data API v3.  I'm the Administrator of the organization.  I'm also the primary owner of the channel.  I have *internal* selected because I'm the only person doing the uploads.  **I'm getting this 403 error every time I select our brand account.** (see below)  It works just fine if I select my own account.

I have researched this quite a bit and couldn't find a solution.  Can you help?
Maybe it has something to do with the channel not being part of ActionJackson? It was originally created under a different account but I have moved it over with full ownership.

If there is another way to upload videos with the Data API other than through this oauth2 method let me know.

My organization is actionjackson.com

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55287870/8327971): indeed it seems that (quote) *it has something to do with the channel not being part of ActionJackson*.

Comment: @user1907377 have you solved this?